# Django: Convert a POST request parameters to query string

Tags: python, django, query-string

As per subject, I am receiving a POST request. I want to convert it to the equivalent GET request and pass it to a template (so I can use it as href target in click-to-sort column headers).

Is there a pre-baked way to do it, or do I need to roll my own?

Cheers,
alf

**UPDATE**

This is what I eventually used. I needed request.REQUEST, so request.POST.urlencode was not cutting it, and request.REQUEST does not have urlencode.

```
import urllib
def buildqs(request):
    "Builds a GET-style query string form http-request"
     #also request.POST.urlencode is possible - 
     #Sadly, request.REQUEST does not have urlencode
     return  urllib.urlencode(request.REQUEST)+"&"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the standard library, [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode). e.g.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
'a=1&b=2'
```

Comment: @Alien Life Form: Please delete the now-useless comment.  Also, don't waste time on "status update" comments.  They convey no information.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
request.POST.urlencode()
```

Comment: This also works - although - strangely - not on request.REQUEST

Comment: Better than accepted answer because it is more succinct and doesn't require import.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

```
request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```